# dynamic MKMap points loading

Tags: ios, multithreading, mkmapview, mkannotation

Im trying to find the best way to work with MKMaps with my needs.

My code is very long so ill just explain.

What do i need to do? (***)

- understand what is the location that the user is interested in.
- get points from the internet for this location.
- load them into the map.
- update the map (cluster annotations) with animation.

How do I do it now?

- in `regionDidChangeAnimated` I call `GetPoints`.
- `GetPoints` starts a NSURLConnection in order to get the points in the region (using region.span.latitudeDelta and region.span.longitudeDelta).
- in `connectionDidFinishLoading` I'm calling `AddPoints`.
- `AddPoints` is checking for every point if its already on the map, if not its added (not directly to the MapView but to a "hidden" AllPointsMap).
- after adding all points into the AllPointsMap Im calling `updateVisibleAnnotations`.
- `updateVisibleAnnotations` is updating the MapView (by separating the `visibleMapRect` to `gridMapRect`s and shows only one MKAnnotation for each one) and takes care to animate the annotations in and out the way they should.

What is the problem?

it works! but its not so smooth, `updateVisibleAnnotations` takes a lot of time and the map is not responding in that time...

So I'm calling `updateVisibleAnnotations` in background, like that:

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateVisibleAnnotations) withObject:nil];`

Its awesome, really smooth mapView animations, not disturbing user interface.

BUT from time to time i get "Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x76c11b0> was mutated while being enumerated".
I can't tell exactly what causing it. But my guess is that main thread is trying to add or remove annotations while background threads are using them.

I have tried using `@synchronized` in `updateVisibleAnnotations` so main thread is not interrupting background thread, but it remained the same.
I have tried using a `self.waitinigForUpdate` BOOL @property to indicate that `updateVisibleAnnotations` is running in background, still get the same error…

Makes me wonder: Maybe this is not the best way doing what I need to do (***), is it??

Comment: Solved the error : **USE GCD!**  - `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`.
But still looking for better ways.

Comment: no this is the best way